# Convert JSON file with arrays to Java object

Tags: java, json, converters

how to convert form JSON with many Arraysinside?
That how is look part of my JSON:

```
    "features": [
            {
                    "geometry": {
                            "coordinates": [
                                    16.91828856,
                                    52.3838415
                            ],
                            "type": "Point"
                    },
                    "id": "ROLN04",
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                            "zone": "A",
                            "route_type": "3",
                            "headsigns": "238",
                            "stop_name": "Rolna"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "geometry": {
                            "coordinates": [
                                    16.88799654,
                                    52.40252503
                            ],
                            "type": "Point"
                    },
                    "id": "RJNJ01",
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                            "zone": "A",
                            "route_type": "3",
                            "headsigns": "251",
                            "stop_name": "Rondo Jana Nowaka-JezioraĹskiego"
                    }
            },
```

I what have Array with Object Stop with coordinates, name Stop, and line of a bus(in JSON that is "headsings"):

```
private Double coordinateY;
private Double coordinateX;
private String nameStop;
private String withLine; ("headsigns" in JSON)
```

My class i look like that:

```
@Autowired
JSON json;
@Autowired
Stop stop;

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
List<String> coordinates;
List<Stop> allStopList = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Stop> convert() {
    try {

        Object obj = parser
                .parse(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("poznanS.json"))));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray stopArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("features");
        for (Iterator stopIndex = stopArray.iterator(); stopIndex.hasNext();) {
            JSONObject stopJSONObject = (JSONObject) stopIndex.next();
            JSONArray coordynateArray = (JSONArray) stopJSONObject.get("geometry");
            stop.setCoordinateY...
            stop.setCoordinateX...
            stop.setNameStop...
            stop.setWithLine...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType`

For example:

```
protected List<TypeList> getTypesOfGroup(String group) {
            WebTarget target = restClient.getWebTargetByPath("typelist/groups").path(group);
            List<TypeList> types = target.request(RestClient.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get(new GenericType<List<TypeList>>() {
                    });
            return types;
        }
```